# linux public hostname management

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

I'm learning about networking, and have a few questions about how a linux hostname works on a network. Let's say my hostname (found when running "hostname" in bash) is "Bob".

If I map my network with nmap, I get something saying "Bob- PTR"

I want to know if it's possible on linux to set a blank hostname, so that other computers scanning the network will not see a host name for the computer. In nmap, I occasionally see devices (like ipods) with no hostname, just an IP address.

My other question is, is there a way to make it so the public hostname is different than the internal hostname? So that I still see "myuser@Bob", wheras other computers on the network see something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same thing, but setting a random hostname and domain.

I think that I want to use a version of this script and the linux built-in word list, but I am not sure yet how to pass it to the running kernel with hostname properly:

```
#!/bin/sh

WORDFILE="/usr/share/dict/words"
NUMWORDS=2



#Number of lines in $WORDFILE


tL=`awk 'NF!=0 {++c} END {print c}' $WORDFILE`

for i in `seq $NUMWORDS`
do
rnum=$((RANDOM%$tL+1))
sed -n "$rnum p" $WORDFILE
done
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. You really need to have an answer for the question. I see you're new so can't comment but perhaps monitor the question, or post a new question